# HTML - img with CSS and text

Tags: html, css

I try to put a picture in the right side of the page. the problem is that there is a text near it, and in some browsers the picture hide the text. I use the next CSS for the `<img>` attribute:

```
.imgP
{
position:relative;
top:10px;
right: 10px;
float:right;
}
```

the text is the next element:

```
<p> bla bla bla... </p>
```

How can I change it, in order that the text would move automatically near the picture?

Comment: Whats the css for the text, and can we see your html?

Comment: You can't use `position` and `float` together (get rid of the position). But you did not provide enough information, so we can't help you more.

Comment: A demo would be helpful.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/, http://placehold.it/

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're trying to achieve it text-wrapping on an image.

The principle for doing this is simple.

Create some HTML markup like this:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" class="imgP" />
<p>My Paragraph text which will wrap around the image...</p>
```

And to make the text wrap the image, you simply float the image to the right:

```
.imgP
{
   float: right;
}
```

A float will cause the horizontal spacing that the image sits on to collapse, and cause the text to fill that area.